# POST Request Failed, unable to login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux

I am getting **Request Failed** error when I am tying to logging in through frontend:
[image]

But, I am able to, when I am entering emailID and password through *thunder client*:
[image]

I am entering correct ID and password here is my request:
[image]

but what I am getting in return is:

[image]

Here is my source code:

### **FRONTEND**

**userAction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "appllication/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login",
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**userReducer.js**

```
import {
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGOUT,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

// reducers
import { userLoginReducer } from "./reducers/userReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
});

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

### **BACKEND**

**userController.js**

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const generateToken = require("../utils/generateToken");

//  @description: Auth user & Get token
//  @route:       POST /api/users/login
//  @access:      Public
exports.authUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
      res.json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        token: generateToken(user._id),
      });
    } else {
      const error = new Error("Invalid email or password");
      error.status = 401;
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("_id: ", user._id);
    error = new Error("Invalid user data");
    error.status = 401;
    next(error);
  }
};

//  @description: Get user profile
//  @route:       GET /api/users/profile
//  @access:      Private
exports.getUserProfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
      res.json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error = new Error("User not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      match: [
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
        "Please enter a valid email address",
      ],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      match: [
        /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
        "Password must contain minimum eight characters, atleast one letter, one number & one speccial character ",
      ],
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

// We are encrypting data before saving it
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ensure, back-end side, you were receiving the email and password properly before even trying to match passwords?

I think the problem lies here:

```
const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "appllication/json",
      },
    };
```

Since "appllication/json" is not a valid Content-Type, it is not parsed like it should. Try removing a 'l'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, am unable to understand what should I remove can you please elaborate more.

Comment: In the above code, replace "appllication/json" by "application/json".